# Remove duplicated tuples from list based on the first entry of tuple

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this one here:

```
test = [('ent1', 24), ('ent2',12), ('ent3',4.5), ('ent1', 4), ('ent2', 3.5)]
```

I would like to remove those tuples from the list where the first element has already appeared. So the desired output would be

```
[('ent1', 24), ('ent2',12), ('ent3',4.5)]
```

I have no idea how to do this. Normally, if I would like to remove exact duplicated tuples, I would use

```
list(set(test))
```

but this is not working in this case. Has anybody an appropriate approach for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a check flag

**Ex:**

```
test = [('ent1', 24), ('ent2',12), ('ent3',4.5), ('ent1', 4), ('ent2', 3.5)]
check_val = set()      #Check Flag
res = []
for i in test:
    if i[0] not in check_val:
        res.append(i)
        check_val.add(i[0])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[('ent1', 24), ('ent2', 12), ('ent3', 4.5)]
```

Answer (score 9):

How do you like the output of `dict(test)`?

```
{'ent1': 4, 'ent2': 3.5, 'ent3': 4.5}
```

Or you may want to convert this back to a list of tuples with

```
>>> list(dict(test).items())
[('ent1', 4), ('ent2', 3.5), ('ent3', 4.5)]
```

Edit: This will keep the last assigned value but you can also keep the first assigned value by reversing first your list:

```
>>> list(dict(reversed(test)).items())
[('ent2', 12), ('ent1', 24), ('ent3', 4.5)]
```

Edit2: If you want to preserve list order, as well, this seems to be a good one-liner solution (inspired by Julien's answer):

```
>>> [(uk,next(v for k,v in test if k == uk)) for uk in dict(test).keys()]
[('ent1', 24), ('ent2', 12), ('ent3', 4.5)]
```

And finally, you with functools.reduce you can get another one-liner:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda lu,i:i[0] in dict(lu).keys() and lu or lu+[i], test, [])
[('ent1', 24), ('ent2', 12), ('ent3', 4.5)]
```

Explanation: `lu` is the list with only unique keys, `i` is the next item from the `test` list. If `i[0]`, i.e. the key of the next element is in `lu` already, we keep `lu`, otherwise we append `i`.

Comment: dict does not keep the order. This is why I have accepted the other answer.

Comment: @WinterMensch Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @WinterMensch In Python 3.6 and later, `dict` *does* keep the order. However, `set` still doesn't keep the order, so your code in the question doesn't preserve order.

Comment: @WinterMensch I think now I found an elegant *and* good 1-liner solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = [('ent1', 24), ('ent2',12), ('ent3',4.5), ('ent1', 4), ('ent2', 3.5)]
deduplicated_test = [(s,[t[1] for t in test if t[0] == s][0]) for s in sorted(set([t[0] for t in test]))]
```

Short and painful to read, sorry.
I don't remember why sorted(set()) works and set() doesn't but anyway...